# Import Error while using new xgboost-distribution

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I'm using the new [xgboost-distribution module](https://pypi.org/project/xgboost-distribution/)

I input the following into my file

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from xgboost_distribution import XGBDistribution

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = load_boston()
    X, y = data.data, data.target
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

    model = XGBDistribution(
        distribution="normal",
        n_estimators=500
    )
    model.fit(
        X_train, y_train,
        eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)],
        early_stopping_rounds=10
    )
```

When I run this code, however, it generates an import error within the xgboost/sklearn.py module file:

```
from xgboost_distribution import XGBDistribution
  File "/Users/timgundersen/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost_distribution/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from xgboost_distribution.model import XGBDistribution  # noqa
  File "/Users/timgundersen/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost_distribution/model.py", line 7, in <module>
    from xgboost.sklearn import XGBModel, _wrap_evaluation_matrices, xgboost_model_doc
ImportError: cannot import name '_wrap_evaluation_matrices' from 'xgboost.sklearn' (/Users/timgundersen/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py)
```

I tried updating `sklearn`, as well as `xgboost` and other modules that sklearn requires.

Why would this be giving me an import error if my computer is updated with all of the correct versions ?

Answer (score 0):

Which `python` version do you use?

In case of `python 3.8`, it should work with `scikit-learn 0.24.1`

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.24.1
```

Comment: Just ran that in terminal, and it is still giving me the same error. Could it be that I need to downgrade one of the versions of xgboost or sklearn?